# WebStorm not recognising Mocha describe() and it()

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, webstorm

I admit that I'm being pedantic here.  I have a Mocha test in WebStorm and WebStorm is complaining about `describe()` and `it()` not being a function type.

[image: Method expression is not of Function type]

I have the `mocha-definitelyTyped` library downloaded, and added to the `tests` folder.

[image: Scopes]

Running Mocha is fine.  Why is WebStorm not resolving the `describe` and `it` methods?

Comment: Are you sure, you set your mocha-definatelyTyped scope correctly? A screenshot of `Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries` + `Manage Scopes` would be helpful.

Comment: @DarekKay Done, cheers.

Comment: Very strange, it looks exactly like my configuration, but my `describe` is recognized correctly.. Have you tried creating another project to see if the problem persists? Also, `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart` sometimes helps in such situations.

Comment: @DarekKay just tried it.  No change... *sigh*.

Comment: @BanksySan   It looks like there was a bug that may have been causing this.  See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18768

Comment: I had the incorrect interface set on the run configuration https://mochajs.org/#interfaces

Answer (score 42):

From the description of the inspection:

> When using libraries that define their own global symbols outside
>   their visible JavaScript code (e.g. describe() in Mocha), it is
>   recommended that you add the corresponding TypeScript type definition
>   file as a JavaScript library in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks |
>   JavaScript | Libraries.

Navigate to the above referenced preference and make sure the `@types/mocha` (this was changed in early 2019 from `mocha-DefinitelyTyped`.  Either is OK.) library is in the list (don't select it).  If it is not in the list, click the `Download...` button, find `mocha` there, and add it.  Then click the `Manage Scopes...` button, find your test directory, click on the library column, and select the `@types/mocha` entry.  See the screenshot below.[image: Screenshot of the referenced preferences page]

Comment: @PositiveGuy what isn't working?  Keep in mind that the IDE will need to refresh its indexes before the change shows.  In my experience, this doesn't happen until you click OK. (Apply by itself doesn't refresh the indexing.

Comment: I'm not sure that `mocha-DefinitelyTyped` is still available. Using the "mocha" or `@types/mocha` worked for me.  I added it using the **Languages & Frameworks** > **JavaScript** > **Libraries** setting.

Comment: @Anovative, you are correct.  It looks like the DefinitelyTyped packages have been renamed to remove DefinitelyTyped.  The "mocha" library stub does point to the DefinitelyTyped repo (as do many other libraries).

Comment: It does not work for me too

Comment: For me it works when right-clicking on a file and selecting "Run" but not when running one specific test (there, I still get `TypeError: describe is not a function`, even after doing the above).

Comment: No matter what I do I am not able to get mocha-DefinetlyTyped or any others besides `@types/7zip-min` to download in my libraries. Im not sure why this is. Is there something additional needed to get that download list populated ?

Comment: @Norbert If you go into *Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Node.ja and NPM*, it should be in the list on that page.  If it is not, you can add it with the + at the bottom left of the window.  Search for it in available packages.  It might just be called 'mocha'.  You could also add it to your devDependencies in your package.json file and run an npm install.

Comment: yea the difference for me was I had mocha installed but not the typescript mocha lib installed.

Comment: adding "mocha" in that way solved it for me.

Comment: Awesome, spent way to long trying to figure this out. Thanks.