# Webstorm 10 mongoose unresolved function with mongoose-DefinitelyTyped installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, webstorm

I recently reinstalled my MEAN stack development environment. I cannot for the life of me get mongoose functions to resolve in Webstorm 10. I have mongoose-DefinitelyTyped and mongodb-DefinitelyTyped installed and checked.

My node.js application runs fine and is usable. I'm using mongoose to do my models. My old development environment was theoretically the same and didn't have the 'cannot resolve x' issue. I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is a bug. There's a similar post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956862/webstorm-not-recognising-mocha-describe-and-it

Comment: may be the same as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17099. I'd suggest creating a support ticket, providing code sample where the methods sre not recognized for you

Comment: As written on that jetbrains tracker you can use e.g. `var User = new require('../models/user');` instead of `var User = require('../models/user');` and the warnings go away. Not sure of unintended consequences..?