# Mocha hooks are not only partially recognised within WebStorm

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webstorm

Another beginner's Mocha question!  I'm struggling to get WebStorm to treat my Mocha hooks as such.  I have followed the guidelines here: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-unit-tests-on-mocha.html

I have followed the guidelines here:
[WebStorm not recognising Mocha describe() and it()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956862/webstorm-not-recognising-mocha-describe-and-it)

I have looked at another project in which Mocha is recognized and believe I have configured it identically but still no luck.

What I am seeing, is as follows:[image]

In which *some* of the hooks are recognized - for example, 'BeforeEach' and 'it', but others, such as 'before' and 'describe' are not.

When I hover over Describe, I get:

[image]

When trying to configure run configurations, I'm unclear which to check:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling `@types/mocha` in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**